# Easy Way To Overload All Methods of a Class

Tags: python

Somewhat unrealistic hypothetical situation, but:

Say I have a new class `Foo` that I've written which constructs an object which is used as input argument for an existing class `Bar`. `Foo` is designed to add some functionality to `Bar`, but I do not want it to interfere with any of my existing jobs that already run. E.g. I want to be very careful that I'm not affecting any of my existing jobs that use `Bar`, because the data that the existing jobs write should be continuous/consistent.

Let's say that for whatever reason, I can't add a kwarg `foo=None` to the constructor for `Bar`. Or I could, but it would be a huge hassle. What I want to do give it an instance of `Foo` that does nothing.

Is there a really straight forward way to overload all the methods of `Foo` so that they do nothing? Or would I be forced to code each method like

```
class DummyFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def method1(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def method2(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

etc?

Comment: It looks like you would be breaking the substitution principle, wouldn't you?

Comment: In most cases, probably. In the situation I had which inspired the question, I wouldn't be.

Comment: Do you only need this for functions? Or for all instances/class attributes as well?

Comment: One has to ask why you need to inherit anything if you're just going the clear all the methods out? Also a subclass won't impact the behavior of parent class instances unless you're manipulating class variables.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp Good question. In the scenario I'm think of it would only be for functions.

Comment: @Pyrce I'm thinking of a situation where say I don't want to have to add lines like `if self.foo is not None: self.foo.method(x)` to my existing code, and can just guarantee that the `Bar` object will always have a `Foo` object that implements `method`. And when I don't want the `Foo` object to do anything I pass the constructor an instance of `DummyFoo`.

Comment: The other possible solution here is to have `Foo` implement all the methods as just `def bar(): pass` and have a `SpecficFoo` class that overrides those methods. It depends on if you have multiple classes that inherit from `Foo` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to override `__getatrribute__`.

```
class Foo:
    blar = 1
    def bar(self):
        print("It's a bar! Scary Bar!")


class DummyFoo(Foo):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if callable(getattr(super(), item)):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs : None
        return None


dummy_foo = DummyFoo()
dummy_foo.bar()  # Should do nothing.
print(dummy_foo.blar)
```

Note, this will resolve ANY attributes, not just the ones on `Foo`. If you need to only limit to attributes that are part of `Foo`, you can do this:

```
class Foo:
    blar = 1

    def bar(self):
        print("It's a bar! Scary Bar!")


class DummyFoo(Foo):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item not in super().__dict__:
            raise AttributeError
        if callable(getattr(super(), item)):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: None
        return None


dummy_foo = DummyFoo()
print(dummy_foo.bing())  # Raises an AttributeError.
```

Comment: For completeness, lambda should be `lambda *args, **kwargs: None` - methods may be be called with keyword arguments.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski You are completely right. I just added that to my answer, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Morgan Thrapp's answer, it may be easier to do this without inheriting.

```
class DummyFoo:

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        '''Raises AttributeError for anything not in Foo.'''
        item = getattr(Foo, name)
        if callable(item):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: None
        return item
```